# Best way to transmit bool with attribute routing

Tags: c#, .net, web

Is there any good example of the transmission bool parameter with attribute routing?

For example I can transform route

```
{controller}/{action}?param=true
```

to

```
{controller}/{action}/param=true
```

but it still "dirty".

Comment: why do you find this "dirty"?

Comment: If you don't want the user to see the bool, try looking at sessions or cookies

Comment: May be you can pass 0 or 1. `{controller}/{action}?param=0` here 0 for false and so on..

Comment: @ManuToMatic because user can see param name in url. This url don't show what user want, it speak at the technical rather then human language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for dummy question (:

Solution is use two attribute like this:

```
[Route("ValuesForFalse/{param=false}")]
[Route("ValuesForTrue/{param=true}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

{controller}/{action}/{param}

param is bool